# Sylius: Channel not found in custom command

Tags: sylius

Using default Sylius `CompositeChannelContext` in custom command gives error, that channel not found.

```
  [Sylius\Component\Channel\Context\ChannelNotFoundException]                                                    
  Channel could not be found! Tip: You can use the Web Debug Toolbar to switch between channels in development.
```

Changing it in Profiler makes no different.

How should I use ChannelContext in Command?

Comment: Currently it's not possible to use channel context in commands when there are multiple channels.
You could add a new context that will return whatever channel you want in CLI mode.
https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.9/book/configuration/channels.html

Comment: Thanks @VictorVasiloi for suggestion, it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating CustomChannelContext with low priority allowed me to bypass this error. Now whenever CompositeChannelContext is called it lastly goes through my CustomChannelContext and get last channel in repository.